# .includes with array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i wonder is there any way to check if in a string there are characters that match the characters in array?

```
const array = ["cake","hello","ok"];
const string = "hello"
let result = string.includes(array)
console.log(result)
// >false
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to switch array and string:

```js
const array = ["cake","hello","ok"];
const string = "hello"
let result = array.includes(string)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: maybe worth to mention, `includes` is implemented for array and string ...

Comment: And the output will be `true` not `false`.

Comment: if the string change to "helloaeeahwbdhbd", how can i find it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some): loop through the array and check if any of the elements match the predicate.

Here checking if `string` [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) as a substring any of the strings in `array`.

```js
const array = ["cake","hello","ok"];
const string = "helloaeeahwbdhbd"
let result = array.some(s => string.includes(s))
console.log(result)
```